# Advertising on Super User (2016)

Tags: discussion, advertising

Software Recommendations advertisement on Super User:

https://meta.superuser.com/a/11136/269798

Even if you think a better ad could be made, please first **upvote it** so that it reaches the required threshold of 6 votes to get displayed, thanks!

The image itself can still be modified, so please post your ideas/designs/images below!
By the way, do you know other QA site where it would make sense to advertise, potentially with a different ad?

Comment: Nicolas, this is flooding our Meta unnecessarily. As discussed, we decided to restrict this to a single question. I'm going to close all but one of these announcements here – please collect your others as answers to the [first announcement's post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2421/185), then delete the redundant questions. Thanks!